# Функции GitHub : Issues, Projects, Pull Requests

Tags: github

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с такими функциями GitHub как **Issues, Projects, Pull Requests**. Для чего они нужны и как правильно с ними работать. У меня есть репозиторий, в котором 2 текстовых файла. И к этому репозиторию надо применить эти функции.
Заранее, огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. **Issues** — это система учёта ошибок, по-английски *bugtracker*.

   Конечно, она не такая навороченная, как, к примеру Jira. Однако разработчики Github-а считают эту простоту преимуществом благодаря гибкости и отсутствию визуального мусора.

   Так как у Github Issues отсутствуют такие важные поля, как «Категория», «Серъёзность», «Статус» и «Компонент», их приходится заменять проставлением различных меток. Вот как это [предлагает делать](https://robinpowered.com/blog/best-practice-system-for-organizing-and-tagging-github-issues/) некто Zach Dunn:

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   Интересной особенность GitHub является то, что нумерация сообщений в Issue Tracker-e является общей с Pull Requests, хотя эти два понятия не пересекаются и находятся в разных категориях.

   Более подробно о Github Issues можно прочитать в [официальной справке](https://guides.github.com/features/issues/).
2. **Projects** — это хранилище заметок. Больше о нём и сказать нечего, кроме упоминания возможности упорядочивать заметки по столбцам (категориям) и строкам. Вот, собственно, и всё. Можете хоть хранить напоминания, хоть организовать доску для [канбана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD_(%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0)).

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. **Pull Requests** — это заявка на принятие ваших изменений в центральный репозиторий. Является неотъемлемой частью [Github Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/).

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   Предполагается, что вы вели разработку в своей, публично доступной копии репозитория — *форке*. Публичность нужна для возможности улучшения вашей копии другими пользователями перед окончательным включением ваших изменений в центральный репозиторий.